# Cant fill in my strings?

Tags: c++

when i run my program i only can fill in the int `gnm_h201` but when i go to the next header file i cant fill in anything and the program just closes.
Here are my codes:

Gemeente.h

```
// Declaratie
// constructie
class Gemeente
{
public:
    int gnm_h201;
    Gemeente()
    {

    };

    // Methode
    void InvoerenGemeente();
};
// implementatie
void Gemeente::InvoerenGemeente()
{
    cout << "Voer uw Gemeente in: "; cin >> gnm_h201;
}
```

Persoon.h

```
class Persoon
{
public:
    int bsn_h202;
    string gnm_dl201;
    string wfactor;
    Gemeente gemeente;

    Persoon()
    {

    };
    // Methode
    void InvoerenPersoon();
    void WeergevenPersoon();
};
// Implementatie
void Persoon::InvoerenPersoon()
{
    cout << "Voer uw naam in: "; cin >> bsn_h202;

    // Functieaanroep
    gemeente.InvoerenGemeente();

    // Toekennen
    gnm_dl201 = gemeente.gnm_h201;
    // Waardenregel toekennen
    wfactor = "fulltime";
}

void Persoon::WeergevenPersoon()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Persoon " << bsn_h202 << " woont in gemeente " << gnm_dl201 << " werkt de werktijdfactor " << wfactor;
    cout << endl;
}
```

And the cpp file

```
#include "Gemeente.h"
#include "Persoon.h"
#include "School.h"
#include "Werkzaam.h"

// Implementatie
int main()
{
    // Constructie
    School school1;
    Werkzaam werkzaam1;
    Persoon persoon1;

    school1.gemeente.InvoerenGemeente();
    persoon1.InvoerenPersoon();
    persoon1.WeergevenPersoon();

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What does "can't" mean?

Comment: @mani66 It skips the `cin` line it automatically goes to the next line so i cant fill in a value for the `strings and or integrers`

Comment: What do you mean by `when i go to the next header file`?

Comment: Can you not reduce the size of your example?  We need to see the smallest code which reproduces the problem.  Also, please [edit] your answer to include the information about what "can't" means.